# How does Windows 7 show the thumbnails of application in taskbar?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

How does Windows 7 show the thumbnails of application in taskbar?

I can even see the movies in these thumbnails playing.
Is it possible to do this with VC++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The live thumbnail previews are created by the [Desktop Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager).

Your application can get access to them by using the [DwmRegisterThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969521.aspx) and [DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969526.aspx) functions. For more information, see the [DWM Thumbnail Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969541.aspx) at MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 to create an MFC application, add the following call somewhere in the CWinApp::InitInstance() method:

EnableTaskbarInteraction(true);

That's all that is required to make your app's previews visible.