# How to scale/zoom window in Windows?

Tags: winapi

This is an unusually short post, but I really don't know where to start. I am trying to find an API in Windows to scale an application window (e.g. down to 50%).

I found a variety of API functions regarding DPI, but I couldn't find anything for the zoom factor. Can anyone help me out?

The closest for Window handling I could find is [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow)

Comment: There is no API to scale a window.  The window is responsible for querying the OS for the user's current scaling factor and then size itself and its contents accordingly.

Comment: so you want to call raw Win32 APIs to draw windows? Why don't just use some UI framework that does that automatically? All modern Windows frameworks can do that automatically

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I obtained a `HWND` reference of a window and would like to scale it to 50%. Think of a mouse hover over the task bar application, you see a preview of it in X%

Comment: Oh, that thing is called a "[DWM thumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/thumbnail-ovw)". Use functions like DwmRegisterThumbnail to create one.

Comment: Thanks Raymond! I could accept that as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Windows 7 show the thumbnails of application in taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342677/how-does-windows-7-show-the-thumbnails-of-application-in-taskbar)

Comment: upvoted that one, thanks!